# Create a subdomain from GoDaddy and point to GCP instance

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns, godaddy-api

*I have a domain registered under the Godaddy and now I want to create a subdomain which points to GCP instance (static address).*

```
So when did a R&D, few are saying that we need to create a zone and then points the provided Namespace address to the Godaddy ?
```

or

```
Just go to Manage DNS in Godaddy -->add -->A type (ipv4) and then points to subdomain -->with destiny IP address
```

Which way is the appropriate way ? can anybody help in this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point of creating a new zone to point a subdomain.
New Zone is like a new Domain. There could be 2 cases where you want to have a new zone -

- Purchasing a new Domain
- Using a subdomain of a domain which is purchased on some other DNS Provider.

In your case, Just add `A Record`  -

1. Go to GoDaddy.
2. Select your Domain.
3. Add a new Record.
4. In Name (Host) Enter name of subdomain.
5. Select Record Type A.
6. In Value add IPv4 Address of GCP instance.
7. Leave everything else default and save.

It will reflect it's changes within next 48hrs (Usually takes few minutes)

Comment: thanks man! I did the same and took around 2 hours and got reflected !

Comment: Awesome @JithinKumarS ! Can you mark this answer as accepted? This will help me.